# Cant delete latest files from all s3 sub-folders using boto3 python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have two Directories under a client ID which has a following structure

**Bucket = adityadataretention**

**client ID = 523180**

```
adityadataretention/523180/source=shopify/yr=2022/mth=10/test1.csv,test2.csv
adityadataretention/523180/source=channel/yr=2022/mth=10/test1.csv,test2.csv
```

I want to iterate to the end of the directory and delete test2.csv for both the events, as you will see in the above link sources are different, one is **shopify** and other is **bots**
I have written the code below for the same

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timezone
today = datetime.now(timezone.utc)

dict = {}


Bucket = 'adityadataretention'

def dictionairy():
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
 
    objects = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=Bucket)

    #print(objects)

    for obj in (objects['Contents']):

         dict[obj["Key"]] = obj["LastModified"]
    
    sortedValue = {k: v for k, v in sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda kv: (kv[1]))}
    print(sortedValue, end=' ')
    
    valuToBeDeleted = sortedValue.popitem()
    # valueToBeDeleted = '523180/source=channel/yr=2022/mth=10/day=11/huditest2.csv
   
     response = s3.delete_object(
      Bucket=Bucket,Key = valuToBeDeleted[0]. # valuToBeDeleted[0] is zero because the 
                                              #outcome is a dictionary so I am taking key
      )
```

This deletes the the data based on the key but only deletes from one directory and not from the other , if I try to run it in loop it deletes all the data.So which means it will delete **test2.csv** from where **source = shopify** and then next it will delete **test1.csv** again where **source = shopify** when it should be deleting **test2.csv** from the other directory where **source = bots**

**How can I achieve the same please suggest or help?**

**UPDATE**

I have figured out the answer here is the code

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from datetime import date
todays_date = date.today()

today = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
dict = {}

# prefix = 'alldata/date'
Bucket = 'adityadataretention'

def dictionairy():
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    #objects_v2 = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=Bucket,Prefix=objects_)
    objects= s3.list_objects(Bucket=Bucket,Delimiter='/')

    for list in ["shopify","channel"]:  #dynamic
            #print("objects ", objects)
        for prefix in objects['CommonPrefixes']:
            object_ = prefix.get('Prefix')
                    #print(object_)
            if object_ == '523180/':
               # print(" went inside")
                files_in_each_buck = s3.list_objects(Bucket=Bucket,Prefix=object_+"source={}/cur_year/cur_mnth/cur_day/".format(list))
                for content in files_in_each_buck.get('Contents',[]):
                    #dict[content['Key']] = content["LastModified"].strftime("%m/%d/%Y/ %H:%M:%S")
                    dict[content['Key']] = content["LastModified"]

                if "{}".format(list) == 'channel':

                    print(" second")
                    channel = {k: v for k, v in sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda kv: (kv[1]))}

                    valuToBeDeleted = channel.popitem()

                    print("value to be deleted", valuToBeDeleted)

                    response = s3.delete_object(
                                Bucket=Bucket,Key = valuToBeDeleted[0]
                    )

                elif "{}".format(list) == 'shopify':
                    print(" first")
                    shopify = {k: v for k, v in sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda kv: (kv[1]))}

                    valuToBeDeleted = shopify.popitem()

                    print("value to be deleted" ,valuToBeDeleted)

                    response = s3.delete_object(
                                 Bucket=Bucket, Key=valuToBeDeleted[0]
                    )

def main():
    # function calling
    dictionairy()

# main function calling
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Did you write this code? I ask because you seem surprised about the way it is behaving. It is creating a dictionary of Keys and Modified dates, sorting them, then extracting the _last_ item. Quite clearly it is only deleting one object, which will be the object in the bucket with the latest `LastModified` date. Is your objective to delete the latest _TWO_ objects, or do you want it to delete the last object in every subdirectory, or is it something else?

Comment: When you say `...mth=10/test1.csv,test2.csv` are you saying that there are two objects (`test1.csv` and `test2.csv`) in that folder, or does the actual name of the object end with `test1.csv,test2.csv`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, I did and I figured out my issue, I have modified the code for every directory now and it works fine , Looking forward to make it dynamic . But issue is resolved from my side

Comment: Great to know you figured it out! Feel free to add an Answer to your own question to help future readers. Or, if you don't think this question will help future readers, feel free to delete this question.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Ill add the answer soon in a day or two

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have posted my code please feel free to improve it

Comment: Code such as `if "{}".format(list) == 'channel'` is a complicated way of writing `if list == 'channel'` given that `list` is a string. Also, don't use `list` as a variable name in Python. It's the name of a Python built-in.

Comment: Yes, the code can be improved but if it works for you, that's great! Could you please confirm the requirements -- is the objective **Within the `523180/` path, delete the oldest object in each of the immediate subdirectories (including sub-directories)**? I ask because your solution specifically mentions `shopify` and `channel` but your sample paths mention `shopify` and `bots`.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein forget bots , its shopify and channel , ill edit the question. also want to ask you if i have many such things in my s3 bucket so lets suppose " if object_ == '523180/':" so lets suppose there are more ID's instead of 523180 and I want to iterate over each and go inside then "object_ = prefix.get('Prefix')" will not get me all the prefixes and I want to get the list of the prefixes. How would I do that ?like instead getting one prefix, I get the list of the prefixes

Comment: Oh, did you figure it out? If so, please add it as an **Answer** rather than putting the Answer in your Question. You are welcome to answer your own Question.